# No job functions found using Blob Trigger

Tags: azure-functions

No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

Issue started coming when we upgrade the .netframework from 4.7 to .netcore 3.0

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow this doc [Migrating from 1.x to later versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#migrating-from-1x-to-later-versions) for the task(you can also create a v3 function, and compare with your current v1 function, to see where needs to be changed).

But upgrading from v1 to later version is difficult and not recommended. For the best migration results, you should create a new function app in a new version and port your existing version 1.x function code to the new app.

If you still have the issue, please provide a sample and I can test it for you.

Comment: Ivan, I have created a new app and updated the latest version. I am facing issue with the blob where it is not reading the file from location and getting issue in portal only, but from local is processed correctly  .Executing 'Functions.uploadexcel' (Reason='New blob detected:uploads/blob.xlsx', Id=255bc280-507e-496e-ae1f-bc70463d8d2d)  Failed method Submission#0+<Run>d__11.MoveNext

Comment: @user1877936 first, when you say "I have created a new app and updated the latest version.", you're creating a .net framework azure function then upgrade to .net core 3.1, right? second, how do you create the azure function in azure portal, directly create a new function in azure portal, or create the function during publish?

Comment: have published the function code using CI/CD pipeline as a ZIP .just manually created the app service plan and the blob storage with the required files. Yes updated the code with .net 5.0 as it was initially built on .net frame .

Comment: Ivan , why it is object reference error with XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(myBlob); when reading the excel from myblob . If I remove the myblob function passed .

Comment: @user1877936, what is the type of myBlob, string or stream or xxx?

Comment: myBlob is a Stream

Comment: @user1877936, please also let me know the package(and the version) you're using for XLWorkbook.

Comment: using the latest version: ClosedXML -Version 0.95.4

Comment: @user1877936, got it. I will give it a try later. and one thing to confirm again, you used it in azure function v3? and run it locally or in azure?

Comment: Yes using V3 and issue occurred in azure portal .

Comment: @user1877936 hi I'm sorry for late response. I'm busy these days, do you mind raising a new question(and add the tag `azure-functions`)? so I can ask my colleagues to look into it.